# Why can't I return an IEnumerable<IGrouping<A,B>> as an IEnumerable<IEnumerable<B>>

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, igrouping

I've used `GroupBy()`, and produced an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey,TValue>>`.

And I can foreach over it, and pass each element (each `IGrouping<TKey,TValue>`) into a method that accepts `IEnumerable<TValue>`

This is unsurprising - `IGrouping<TKey,TValue>` implements `IEnumerable<TValue>`

But if I define a method that accepts `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<B>>`, then I can't directly pass in the output of `GroupBy()`, even though it is an `IEnumerable<>` and every element inside it is an `IEnumerable<B>`

Why?

Comment: It works for me. Post the exact method signature and how you're calling it.  My guess is your `B` doesn't match `TValue`.

Comment: `IEnumerable<out T>` is covariant, so it should work. See this [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mkSSXz).

Comment: Covariance/Contraviance was introduced into C#4. Hence if you are compiling in VS2008, this would not work.

Comment: Ah, yes, I'm compiling against .NET 3.5

I knew vaguely that covariance was relevant to this, but I thought that what was added in C#4 was the ability to control it in your own generic classes, hadn't realised that framework classes couldn't do it before then either.

Thanks!

Comment: @Aron or Brondahl make it an answer, making this a proper question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by several people (and indeed, as I sort of knew in the back of my head) this is simply a covariance issue, and only breaks in a pre-.NET 4 environment.